# Are SQL Subquery more efficient

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Trying to understand this, but code efficiency increased more than 10x when I stopped using subquery. Table2 has about 5000 rows, while table1 is pretty huge, a few hundred thousand.

Original Statement

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE indexedCol IN (
   SELECT indexedCol 
   FROM table2 
   WHERE iCol2 = "somevalue"
)
```

So somehow this is way more efficient.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE indexedCol IN 
  (*comma separated result of SELECT FROM table2*)
```

Is there something I am missing here? Or subquery is never a good idea.

Comment: Compare the explain outputs. Also test JOIN instead of subquery.

Comment: And run each query twice if comparing execution time.

Comment: When running a subquery in the `WHERE` clause, it is ran for every single row in `table1` to determine if it should be kept or not. The second method is significantly faster simply because it already has the relevant values and doesn't have to sift through the entirety of `table2` to find them every time. Generally in situations like this I store the results of the subquery in a temporary table and use the  temporary table in the `WHERE` clause instead so it's not searching through as much data.

Comment: @Jesse -- most SQL implementations would not do that.

Comment: @Hogan That's why MySQL is generally considered the worst database. It's popular because it's cheap, but you get what you pay for.

Comment: Join with the subquery instead of using `WHERE IN`. This doesn't have the same performance problem.

Comment: everyone is assuming this is a correlated sub-query -- but I don't think it is.  Is it correlated?

Comment: @Hogan I'm not seeing anyone make that assumption. I think what folks are suggesting is that `FROM table WHERE column IN (SELECT anothercolumn FROM sometable)` may get executed once for each record in `table` and that behavior may just be how mysql works as its optimization steps aren't as great as other databases. I don't know whether that is true or not as I'm not a MySQL expert, but that's how I'm reading this comment section. Barmar is suggesting that's the way mysql operates, and jarlh's suggestion to switch to a join makes me believe they are accurate about mysql's lack of optimization.

Comment: @JNevill and Barmar -- Look at this db fiddle -- you can clearly see in the execution plan a note that says "using join buffer (block nested loop)"  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0cdb6/2  So lets get over this mysql just does not optimize this stuff POV

Comment: I'm not making an assumption that it's correlated.

Comment: @Hogan It might depend on the specifics of the tables, the cardinality of the indexes, etc. I've definitely seen cases where the query plan was performing the subquery repeatedly for each value of `indexedCol`. I've seen it with a query where the subquery just returns one row, but the full query takes forever.

Comment: @Barmar -- yes of course, I've see it many times too. But never with a non-correlated sub-query that is independent -- every platform will run that once.  It is one of the simplistic optimizations to write in a compiler.  It is the first one you implement.

Comment: @Hogan I almost never write correlated subqueries and that's not where I've seen it. It's usually something like `WHERE id IN (select id from table where date > '...')`. It might also be something the MySQL developers have fixed in recent versions.

Comment: That's good to know @Hogan. I appreciate the real life example :)

Comment: @Barmar -- wow that sounds painful.

Answer (score 1):

The real issue is the sub-query correlated?   What do I mean by that?  If the sub-query references table1.  If it doesn't then then answer is simple -- if you have two queries

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
```

and

```
SELECT indexedCol 
FROM table2 
WHERE iCol2 = "somevalue"
```

The time it take to run one of them is less than the time it takes to run both of them.  This could be even worse (as suggested in the comments) if one of them is run for every row.

This query could be rewriten to use a join like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
JOIN TABLE2 on TABLE1.indexedCol = TABLE2.indexedCol and TABLE2.iCol2 = 'some value'
```

Which will probably solve your problem.

Comment: This does solve the performance issue on execution time with 1 SQL statement. How will you approach this if it is an `UPDATE` statement instead? example `UPDATE table1 SET col1 = 1 WHERE col2 IN (SELECT colx FROM table2 WHERE colx = "somevalue")`